# Add COLUMN that contains data count based on 'where'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know the query where I can get the normal set of columns and add a column that contains the number of records in database..

For example, let's say I have these data..

```
ColA   ColB   ColC
----   ----   ----
1AB1   CARR   APPL
2BC1   APPL   APPL
1AB1   MAXR   APPL
```

from those lines, I would like to generate these columns

```
ColA   ColB   ColC   Count
----   ----   ----   -----
1AB1   CARR   APPL     2
```

A. This is my current select statement so far..

```
SELECT top 1 myTBL.* from mydb WHERE ColA = '1AB1'
```

B. But i couldn't seem to add the following code to get my fourth column..

```
SELECT count(myTBL.*) as Count from mydb WHERE ColA = '1AB1'
```

P.S. I would like to get a select statement that combines A and B select statements that I have.  The error I'm getting says something about GROUP BY clause.. I'm having a hard time to understand this.. I hope you could formulate the correct select statement I can use for the given example..  Thanks for all the help..

Comment: "SELECT ColA  , ColB   ,ColC ,count(ColA ) count
from mydb WHERE ColA = '1AB1'
group by ColA   ,ColB   ,ColC " hope this help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ColA, ColB, ColC, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA) AS Count
FROM mydb
WHERE ColA = '1AB1'
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d17a3/1/0)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, but, without an obvious primary key, analytic functions (aka windowing functions) look a good choice.

```
select cola, colb, colc, cnt as "Count" from (
select
cola,
colb,
colc,
row_number () over (partition by cola order by colb) rn,
count (*) over (partition by cola) cnt

from
table1

where cola = '1AB1'
) as d
where rn = 1
```

This gives:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------+
|    cola    |    colb    |    colc    | Count |
+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| 1AB1       | CARR       | APPL       |     2 |
+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this if u just want the count of ColA

```
SELECT top 1 cola,colb,colc, (SELECT count(*) from mytbl t2 WHERE t2.ColA = t1.colA) 
FROM mytbl t1 
WHERE cola = '1AB1'
```

when you using subqueries you cant use mytbl.*

and a other way would be this:

```
Select t1.*,t2.count 
FROM mytbl t1 ,
(SELECT cola,count(*) as "count" from mytbl t2 group by cola) t2
where t1.cola = t2.cola
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query below will group and count the values in the table on the COLA and link back to the original table on ColA with the count.

```
SELECT myTable.ColA , myTable.ColB, myTable.ColC, ColASummary.ColA_Count 
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT ColA, COUNT(ColA) AS ColA_Count 
FROM myTable 
GROUP By ColA
)  AS ColASummary
ON myTable.ColA = ColASummary.ColA
```

If the same is needed for the other columns then additional summary tables can be linked in this way.